# How to echo multiple results from database

Tags: php

How do I echo multiple results. Currently this displays recipe names but I want to be able to echo the steps from the database as well. So the field in the database would be step 1.

```
 <?php
    if (isset($_POST['search'])) {
        $ingredient1 = $_POST['dropdown1'];
        $ingredient2 = $_POST['dropdown2'];
        $ingredient3 = $_POST['dropdown3'];

        $recipes = mysql_query("
            SELECT DISTINCT `name`
            FROM `recipe` r
            INNER JOIN `recipe_ingredients` ri
            ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
            WHERE ri.ingredient_id IN (".$ingredient1.",".$ingredient2.",".$ingredient3.")
        ");
        echo '<section id="results">';
        while ($recipe = mysql_fetch_assoc($recipes)) {
            echo $recipe['name'].'<br />';
        }
    }
    echo '</section>';
    ?>
```

This threw up an error. : PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting ']' in \PDC3\sites\c\cupboard2stomach.com\public_html\php\get.php on line 97

```
echo $recipe['name'].'<br />';
echo $recipe['step1'].'<br />';
```

No error but doesn't display the results.

```
 echo $recipe['name','step1'].'<br />';
```

[image]
This is the recipe table

[image]

```
echo '<section id="results">';
    while ($recipe = mysql_fetch_assoc($recipes)) {
        echo $recipe['name'].'<br />';
        echo $recipe['step1'].':','<br />';
        echo $recipe['step2'].':','<br />';
        echo $recipe['step3'].':','<br />';


    }
}
echo '</section>';
```

These are the results I get back

Comment: I can't see `step1` column in select fields of your query.

Comment: You need to show us the error and what your mysql tables look like.

Comment: Your sql query appears to be only selecting one column - 'name'

Comment: Add mysql_real_escape_string like, $ingredient1 = mysql_real_escape_String($_POST['dropdown1']); to protect from sql injection.

Comment: `mysql_real_escape_string()` will not help unless you quote the parameters in the SQL, however to prevent SQL injection long term use parameterised queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT r.`name`, r.`step1`
FROM `recipe` r
INNER JOIN `recipe_ingredients` ri
ON r.id = ri.recipe_id
WHERE ri.ingredient_id IN ('".$ingredient1."', '".$ingredient2."', '".$ingredient3."')
GROUP BY r.`name`
```

Comment: echo $recipe['step1'].'<br />';

Is this wrong? Because when I run it, the results are "Beans on Toast and Step 1" It doesn't actually show me step1.

Comment: I made edit... instead of DISTINCT is used GROUP BY

Comment: That still only displays the word step 1

Comment: I think you have to use apostrohes around the ingredients-variables in the in-condition of the query. (when it's not only numeric values)

Comment: @bestprogrammerintheworld I've done that I think, I've edited the post to show the results.

Comment: I have done another edit. Use table specificators in query

Comment: That didn't work but I've gone back to using DISTINCT and it's working now. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I realised what it was. I was using ' rather than `.

Answer (score 0):

Your query only returns the name, and only once for each time `name` occurs.

Inside your while loop, execute a new query to find the steps for each recipe `name`, and loop through the steps to echo them separately.